# Input into a polynomial regression formula with Python

Tags: python, numpy, regression, nonlinear-functions

I inherited a project in the middle of pandemonium and to makes matters worse I am just learning python.

I managed to implement a polynomial function into my code and the results
are the same as the ones posted in the examples of this web page. 
[z = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 5)]

However, I will like to know how to modify the program so I can insert an input of one of the know values of y to find x.

In other words. I have x and y arrays where:
- array x holds values for know kilograms weights (0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
- array y (0.074581967, 0.088474754, 0.106797419, 0.124461935, 0.133726833)

I have a program who reads a load of weight and the tension created by a phidget and generates the array to be used by this program.

What I need to accomplish is to read the next value from the phidget and be able to convert the reading into kilograms, from within the provided array.

Is there a way to do this? I feel I am only missing a line of code but I don't know how to implement the results of the returned values from the formula. (z)

Thanks in advance.

## CODE ADDED AS REQUESTED

```
from Phidgets.PhidgetException import PhidgetException
from Phidgets.Devices.Bridge import Bridge, BridgeGain

import datetime
import os
import re
import sys
import time
import numpy


wgh = list()
avg = list()
buf = list()
x = []
y = []


def nonlinear_regression():   # reads the calibration mapping and generates the conversion coefficients

    fd = open("calibration.csv", "r")

    for line in fd:
        [v0, v1] = line.split(",")
        x.append(float(v0))
        y.append(float(v1[:len(v1) - 1]))

    xdata = numpy.array(x)
    ydata = numpy.array(y)


    z = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 5)      

    return z       


def create_data_directory():   # create the data directory
    if not os.path.exists("data"):
        os.makedirs("data")

def parse_config():   # get config-file value
    v = int()

    config = open("config.properties", "r")
    for line in config:
        toks = re.split(r"[\n= ]+", line)
        if toks[0] == "record_interval":
            v = int(toks[1])

    return v

def read_bridge_data(event):   # read the data
    buf.append(event.value)

def record_data(f_name, date, rms):
    if not os.path.isfile(f_name):
        fd = open(f_name, "w")
        fd.write("time,weight\n")
        fd.write(datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%H:%M"))
        fd.write(",")
        fd.write(str(rms) + "\n")
        fd.close()
    else:
        fd = open(f_name, "a")
        fd.write(datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%H:%M"))
        fd.write(",")
        fd.write(str(rms) + "\n")
        fd.close()
    print("Data recorded.")

def release_bridge(event):   # release the phidget device
    try:
        event.device.closePhidget()
    except:
        print("Phidget bridge could not be released properly.")
        sys.exit(1)


def main():

    create_data_directory()

    RECORD_INTERVAL = parse_config()        # get the config-file value
    calibrate = nonlinear_regression()      # get calibration function; use like: calibrate(some_input)
    bridge = Bridge()

    try:
        bridge.setOnBridgeDataHandler(read_bridge_data)
        bridge.setOnDetachHandler(release_bridge)   # when the phidget gets physically detached
        bridge.setOnErrorhandler(release_bridge)   # asynchronous exception (i.e. keyboard interrupt)
    except:
        print("Phidget bridge event binding failed.")
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        bridge.openPhidget()
        bridge.waitForAttach(3000)
    except:
        print("Phidget bridge opening failed.")
        sys.exit(1)

    last_record = int()
    while (True):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        f_name = "data\\" + datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%B_%d_%Y") + ".csv"

        curr = time.time() * 1000
        if (curr - last_record) > (RECORD_INTERVAL * 1000):
            try:
                bridge.setDataRate(10)
                last = time.time() * 1000
                bridge.setEnabled(0, True)
                while (time.time() * 1000 - last) < 1000:   # collects over 1 sec
                    pass
                bridge.setEnabled(0, False)
            except:
                print("Phidget bridge data reading error.")
                bridge.setEnabled(0, False)
                bridge.closePhidget()
                sys.exit(1)
            vol = sum(buf) / len(buf)

            del buf[:]
            last_record = curr

            record_data(f_name, date, vol)   # replace curr with calibrated data

        #THIS IS WHERE I WILL LIKE TO INCORPORATE THE CHANGES TO SAVE THE WEIGHT                
            #record_data(f_name, date,  conversion[0] * vol + conversion[1])   # using the linear conversion function
        else:
            time.sleep(RECORD_INTERVAL - 1)   # to reduce the CPU's busy-waiting

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please add your own code. For now it is not clear what do you want.

Comment: Basically is to be able to read the input provided by a USB interface  phidget, which I already do, and use that current reading to convert to kilograms or find the corresponding X value.

Comment: What input your are reading from USB interface phidget? What type does it have?

Comment: zveryansky ~ the input from the phidget is saved into vol (as in voltage) because that's what the phidget "returns". I don't have it defined as any type but it should receive a floating point. 0.1934234.

Comment: @codewarrior. Thank you for the formula.

When implementing the code these are the findings:
vol = 0.19580114 (reading from phidget av.)
vol_calibrated = 0.094488083

however is vol who I want to have converted (the phidged readings)
from voltage to kilos. In other words I get the voltage and should find the 
corresponding kilos.

Kilo   Voltage
0.0   0.0851251612903
0.5   0.10802704918
1.0   0.129768095238
1.5   0.152979180328
2.0   0.17526862069

Your input is well appreciated.

Comment: To go from y (voltage) to x (kilos), simply reverse the order of the arguments to polyfit: `z = numpy.polyfit(y, x, 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear conversion function from the calibrations is returned by `numpy.polyfit` as an array of coefficients. Since you passed 5 for the degree argument of `polyfit`, you will get an array of six coefficients:

f(x) = ax<sup>5</sup> + bx<sup>4</sup> + cx<sup>3</sup> + dx<sup>2</sup> + ex + f

Where a, b, c, d, e, and f are the elements of the `z` array returned by `nonlinear_regression`.

To implement the linear conversion formula, simply use the power operator `**`, the elements of `z`, and the value of `vol`:

`vol_calibrated = vol**5 * z[0] + vol**4 * z[1] + vol**3 * z[2] + vol**2 * z[3] + vol * z[4] + z[5]`

Or more generally:

```
degree = len(z) - 1
vol_calibrated = sum(vol**(degree-i) * coeff for i, coeff in enumerate(z))
```

Comment: Thank you @codewarrior. You are a life saver, and a job saver for that matter. My initial test results are positive. I'll test with more weight now.